Why is it saying I have 4 positional arguments?
Here is my code and when I run it I get an error message saying "TypeError: integrand() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" but my integrand() has 3 positional arguments so I do not understand why it is saying I have 4 postitional arguments.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
H0 = 70.0  # Hubble constant in km/s/Mpc
Omega_r0 = 0.0  # Radiation density parameter (ignored)
t0 = 1 / H0  # Approximation for the age of the universe in billions of years 

# Define Omega_M0 and Omega_Lambda0 pairs
Omega_m0_values = 0.31
Omega_lambda0_values = [-0.31, 0.69, 1.7289, 1.728]

# Function to integrate
def integrand(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    return 1.0 / np.sqrt((Omega_m0 / a) + (Omega_lambda0 * a**2) + (1-(Omega_m0-Omega_lambda0)))
                         
# Functiion to solve Friedmann Equation
def solve_friedmann(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    result, _ = quad(integrand, 0, a, args=(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0))
    return result / H0

#Generate a range of scale factor
a_values = np.linspace(0.1, 1.9, 100)
# Calculate corresponding time (t) values
t_values = [solve_friedmann(a, Omega_m0_values, Omega_lambda0_values) for a in a_values]    
# Calculate H0(t - t0)
x_values = H0 * (np.array(t_values) - t0)

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
for Omega_m0 in Omega_m0_values:
    for Omega_lambda0 in Omega_lambda0_values:
            x_values, a_values = solve_friedmann(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0)
plt.plot(x_values, a_values, label=f"Ω_M0={Omega_m0}, Ω_Λ0={Omega_lambda0}")
plt.xlabel('H_0(t-t_0)')
plt.ylabel('a')
plt.title('Scale Factor Evolution for Different Ω_M0 and Ω_Λ0 pairs')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)                                                     
plt.show()


I remove one argument from the integrand() but still give the same error message so I do not know what is wrong.

The error means that though integrand is defined with three parameters, it is called with four arguments. I will guess that quad applicates integrand to 4 arguments.

This comes from how arguments are being passed to the integrand function within the quad function. arg should only contain the extra parameters needed by integrand besides the integration variable, which in your case are Omega_m0 and Omega_lambda0. Also, you have a problem with the way the square roots are handled. Here is a suggestion on how to do it:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H0 = 70.0  
t0 = 1 / H0  

Omega_m0_values = [0.31]  
Omega_lambda0_values = [-0.31, 0.69, 1.7289, 1.728]

def integrand(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    expr = (Omega_m0 / a) + (Omega_lambda0 * a**2) + (1 - (Omega_m0 - Omega_lambda0))
    return 1.0 / np.sqrt(expr) if expr > 0 else 0

def solve_friedmann(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    result, _ = quad(integrand, 1e-8, a, args=(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0), limit=100)
    return result / H0

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
a_values = np.linspace(0.1, 1.9, 100)
for Omega_m0 in Omega_m0_values:
    for Omega_lambda0 in Omega_lambda0_values:
        t_values = [solve_friedmann(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0) for a in a_values]
        x_values = H0 * (np.array(t_values) - t0)
        plt.plot(x_values, a_values, label=f'Ω_M0={Omega_m0}, Ω_Λ0={Omega_lambda0}')

plt.xlabel('H_0(t-t_0)')
plt.ylabel('a')
plt.title('Scale Factor Evolution for Different Ω_M0 and Ω_Λ0 pairs')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


which gives

